# how to stop my cell from resizing when jQuery animate effect begin?

Tags: jquery, css

I have code a 2x2 DIV table and i want the left side of the cell appear when `mouseover` right cell and the left cell will be hidden when `mouseleave` the right cell using jQuery animate effect.

However, I notice my right cell has a bounce effect or resize whenever the animate effect start. can anyone advise me how prevent my right cell from resizing?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#top, #bottom')
  .mouseover(function () {
    $('.divTableCell1').stop(true, false).animate({
      width: "300px",
      opacity: "1"
    });
  })
  .mouseleave(function () {
    $('.divTableCell1').stop(true, false).animate({
      width: "100px",
      opacity: "0"
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  float: right;
}
.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell1, .divTableHead, .divTableCell2 {
  /*border: 1px solid #999999;*/
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
.divTableCell1 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
.divTableCell2 {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.divTableCell2 img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">

    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell1">This is Menu 1</div>

      <div id="top" class="divTableCell2">
        <img src="img/alert.png" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell1">This is Menu 2</div>

      <div id="bottom" class="divTableCell2">
        <img src="img/setting.png" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: When I run the snippet on my end (running FF 47) it runs as you say is expected, the right blocks don't change size when I hover on them to reveal the left blocks. Which browser have you checked this on?

Comment: Hi Roko, I use google chrome. there should be a bounce or shift effect at the right cell left border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give `overflow: hidden;` for stop bounce of left border of right element.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#top, #bottom')
  .mouseover(function () {
    $('.divTableCell1').stop(true, false).animate({
      width: "300px",
      opacity: "1"
    });
  })
  .mouseleave(function () {
    $('.divTableCell1').stop(true, false).animate({
      width: "100px",
      opacity: "0"
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
body 
{
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
font-size: 100%; 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.divTable {
 margin-top: 100px;
}
.divTableRow {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    height: 55px;
}
.divTable {
width: 100%;
text-align: right;

}
.divTableCell2 img {
 height: 55px;
 width: 70px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.in_l {
 display: inline-block;

}
.divTableCell2 {
 background-color: dodgerblue;
 cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.divTableCell1 {
 width: 100px;
    height: 55px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 -4px 0 0;
   line-height: 6rem;
       padding-left: 10px;
 text-align: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div class="divTable">
     <div class="divTableBody">

    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell1 in_l">This is Menu 1</div>

      <div id="top" class="divTableCell2 in_l">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ILEhfiz.png" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell1 in_l">This is Menu 2</div>

      <div id="bottom" class="divTableCell2 in_l">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8IQhev1.png" />
      </div>
    </div>

     </div>
   </div>
```